# Owl Carousel: Simple slider working in Chrome only. Does not work in Safari or Firefox

Tags: jquery, carousel, owl-carousel

Here's a link to the problem in action: http://ichael.net/files/slider-issue.html

If you load it in Chrome, it works fine. But in Safari or Firefox the 2nd and 3rd slides do not display. Any help as to why?

Sorry the next/previous links are hard to see, but theyre there right in the middle of either side.

Comment: Your link is broken.